# Same data source in whole solution

Tags: wpf, datasource, expression-blend

Lets assume that my solution contains 2 projects, named Controls and Forms.
In the first one I define my Controls, and in the second one I have pages that are using the controls.

The project Forms, contains a DataSource. The DataSource contains a property named (let's say) Foo (string).

1. Am I able to reference the same properties of the DataSource from the "Controls" project?
2. **If not**, Is there any other way to have something like a Global variable in the whole solution

To be more specific on my example: My Control contains (amongst others) a button. I want on button click to change the value of Foo, so that it can be referenced later from a page in Forms (that does not contain this Control).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Forms` project must reference `Controls` project. So, if you don't want cyclic reference, you have to either:

1. add third project, say, `Common`, move there the `DataSource` and
   reference to it from both `Controls` and `Forms` (cleanest way)
2. move your `DataSource` to `Controls` project (dirty way)

Comment: Regarding the second option, do you mean "move"? I need to reference it from both projects.

Comment: I don't know what the DataSource is, some kind of your class? If so, then just put the implementation of the class in Controls library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set your `DataContext` on the `MainWindow`, then you can easily access it from any controls that are in that XAML. You can use a `RelativeSource Binding` to do so:

From a control that is displayed in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Controls:SomeControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}" />
```

This `Binding Path` will set the `DataContext` of the `SomeControl` control to the same value that is set in the `MainWindow.DataContext`. If you wanted to set the `DataContext`of the `SomeControl` control a property of the `MainWindow.DataContext` object value, then you could do this:

```
<Controls:SomeControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}" />
```

Comment: what do you mean MainWindow? where should this be in? As I said, I have 1 solution with 2 projects inside

Comment: What do I mean 'MainWindow'??? Why have you tagged this question with WPF if you're not using WPF? If you are using WPF, then how can you ask what do I mean by `MainWindow`? It should be in `MainWindow.xaml`, your main application window.

Comment: Sorry then, I thought WFP was a general term. I am using Blend for Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I *was* wondering why you kept mentioning forms... if you're using WinForms (or any other language) then you'd be better off editing your question and replacing the WPF tag with whatever language that you're *actually* using. At least people writing *your* language will be able to help then, rather than just WPF developers.

Comment: Forms is just the name of the project, which contains .xaml pages. The Controls project contains both .xaml and .cs pages. Should I remove WPF and keep Blend?

Comment: Oh, so it *is* a WPF Application... leave it as it is then.